# Need more memory to install Nova 3 Near Orbit on Samsung Galaxy S2

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, storage

I have a Samsung Galaxy S2, running Android 4.0.3.

I want  to install Nova 3 Near Orbit on this device. I need 2 gigabyte of memory to install the game, but I only have 1.97 gigabytes in total.

How can i get the other 3 megabyte? I have 11 gigabyte of space on my phone, and I also have an SD card with 14 gigabyte.

Answer (score 1):

You can get free storage space the same way you do on your PC:

- Uninstall some apps you're not using. You might find it useful to go into the device **Settings**, then **Apps** (or **Applications manager**), then press the menu key and choose **Sort by size** to see which are taking up the most space.
- If you have lots of videos, photos, or music in your internal storage, delete them, or move them to your SD card.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to add additional RAM to your Android device (as you've tagged your question "RAM" I assume you are meaning RAM). So: sorry, you won't be able to solve this.

Comment: The OP is confused. Looking at the app's requirements on Google Play, it means non-volatile storage, not RAM.

Comment: Well, two things: 1) internal storage cannot be increased either (except for some ugly hacks I'd never propose, especially not anyone confusing RAM with storage), and 2) as the OP doesn't report back, the issue seems obsolete...